# Override the "HTTP Request Defaults" values in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

The question is related to functioning of "HTTP Request Defaults" feature available in Jmeter.

Scenario: 1
In HTTP Request Defaults, we have two request parameters "from=1" and "size=10". These parameters are passed to every request by default.

However, there are two requests out of 100 where we don't need these parameters at all.

Is there a strategy we can follow to override the HTTP defaults for this particular scenario?

Answer (score 1):

So, your question is to remove those extra arguments from those specific HTTP Requests.

In that case,

You can remove the argument (using beanshell preprocessor) by the index if you know the index

`ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().removeArgument(2)`

or by the argument name

`ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().removeArgument(name)`

check this for other methods

https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Arguments.html